# Framework using OAuth on iPhone for my site

Tags: iphone, oauth, any

I've been searching for a long while for a framework that will connect my iphone to any site using OAuth, int his case my own site.

I've seen MPOAuthMobile and OAuthConsumer, none of them worked for me and reading the comments many people are having issues.

There are plenty of libraris to connect to Twitter, but could someone tell me if there is a good framework with a good tutorial that explains how to get it done. Even changing an actual framework for twitter to make it work for my site would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
// See tutorial on OAuth integration with twitter.
// http://icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/